# Adding style to ActionBar drop down spinner makes it not a drop down

Tags: android, android-widget, styles, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm using this tutorial:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

I set a drop down list theme like this

```
<!-- style the list navigation -->
<style name="MyDropDownNav" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

and now pressing the spinner causes it to show up centered on the screen instead of as a drop down. Has anyone run into this? I'm using exactly what they said in the example. Even if I remove the text color and just have the empty style that is based on the parent, the spinner appears in the middle of the screen. Has anyone discovered a way to fix this?

Edit: One more thing I forgot to mention, the style does not even update the text to be white.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to set the text to white? I'm trying to do the same thing!

Comment: For me, "android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar" couldn't be found as a resource... No idea why, and I can even go to it's declaration in the android styles.xml and it's their!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution, the parent is incorrect in the example. It should be:

```
parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
```

Comment: for me parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner" and I'm trying to set text color to white. It always appears black on black background. Can you provide your full style, that may help me.